# Installation on Cilk Plus on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, cilk-plus

How to install the CilkPlus on Mac OS X?

When I checked g++ version on my Mac it showed the following:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

I do have downloaded the Intel Cilk Plus SDK build 4421 from their [website](https://www.cilkplus.org/download#block-views-cilk-tools-block-1).

But I dont know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

There is an implementation of LLVM/Cilk Plus at https://cilkplus.github.io/ .